# How can I view the parameter value of custom events logged in firebase analytics via firebase dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I think I have managed to setup the logging of custom events in firebase analytics (yeah!). If I go to the firebase dashboard I can see that the event and the related parameters are properly logged. Now the question is: how can I see the data in the firebase dashboard?

It looks like I have an option to see the parameters value in the last 30 minutes but how can I see the parameters value from yesterday or the current week? it looks like i have 92 events as per image below. How can I see the parameter values I have uploaded?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: at a top right corner there is an option to select date range, based on your screenshot it says November 8 to November 11, 2020